# Maximum and minimum of $y = 4x-8*(\cos(x))$ between $-\pi$ and $\pi$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have found that the maximum of this function is at $\pi$, where the function will equal $$4\pi+8,$$ which is approximately $20$. However, I tried to get the minimum value, and it was incorrect. The derivative I got as $$4- 8(\sin(x)).$$ I set the derivative $=0$. After simplification, I got $$\sin(x) =\frac{1}{2}.$$ Do I then plug in the $\arcsin$ for $x$? Have I made a mistake anywhere along the road? What would be the proper steps to follow?

Comment: There lies the mistake. Derivative is $4 + 8sinx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $\cos(x)$ is $-\sin(x)$, so the derivative of your function is $4+8\sin(x)$. So your solution is $\arcsin(-1/2) = -\frac{\pi}{6}$.